# How to track product cost over time for a POS system?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, point-of-sale

I am designing a Point Of Sale "POS" database while using MySQL as my DBMS.

When adding products to the products database, I add the product name (ie. "Coca-Cola 2.L") and the UPC code, cost, price, department, supplier and the quantity.

So if I receive an order of 1000 bottles which cost me $1 per bottle

Then let's say 2 months down the road, I have only 100 bottles left in stock "my cost for these is $100". Now, I ordered 5,000 bottles more, but this time because I ordered 5,000 the supplier is giving me a 0.10 off each bottle (ie. cost of $0.90 each.) So, the cost is $4500 for my second order. I want to ensure that I track my profit very accurately. Therefore, the 100 that I bought at $1 I want to be able to track those separately at the $1 cost and the new order at the $0.90 cost.

The way I currently track cost for each sale item, by reading the current cost from the product table and I save it in the sales_transactions_items table along with the sold price, transaction_id, and product_id.

The issue that I am having now is that when I received the 5000 bottle, I changed that cost from $1 to $0.90 which made my profit goes up by (100 bottles x $0.10 saving per bottle) 100x0.10 = $10 in profit that I did not actually profited. After the quantity is sold, this discrepancy occurred because the the quantity value reached 5100 bottles where 100 were purchase at $1 and 5,000 were purchased at $0.90 each.

My question: how to I solve for this issue where I can truly capture how much each item cost me.

Comment: You need another table. One for products, and one for purchases

Comment: how can this help me identifying that the first 1000 were purchased at $1 and the 5000 at $0.90? the item_id and the UPC code are still the same

Comment: Because you would store both events - product_id, date, unit_price (or total), and quantity

Comment: I am still not clear on how that will solve the problem. Do you mind help me understand the solution more? I would appreciate a detailed answer.

Comment: Record your purchases with date/time, cost, number of items purchased and number of items unsold in a table. Record your sales with date/time, number of items, and the cost of those items.  You probably want to run a FIFO system so that you sell the oldest items first.  If you sell 300 items, 100 of them at the old price and 200 at the new price, you internally record two sale item lines, one for each purchase price.  If the items are individually trackable (have a serial number — unlike the average bottle of Coke, but very like the average computer), then you do things differently again.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for your explanation. The last thing that I would need to understand is how to ensure that the value of `number` column stay > -1. Also, in the case of a 2 transactions running in the same exact time, I need "somehow" to tell MySQL to lock the table until the transaction is completed.

Comment: Normally, I'd apply a constraint on the column: `CHECK(number >= 0)`.  That's more or less standard SQL (the concept is standard; I'd need to review the notation), but I don't know offhand whether MySQL supports the declaration and enforcement of such constraints.  As to simultaneous update: that's what transactions and a DBMS are for.  If you're using an appropriate engine (InnoDB for MySQL, I believe), then the DBMS handles that automatically.  You do all the modify operations for the sale in a single transaction, and the DBMS prevents transactions from interfering with each other.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am working on this. I will let you know if something come up.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Thank you so much. How, would I handle the returns? How would I know what purchase id would I add the items to?

Comment: There are various possibilities — none of them trivial. If you've got a receipt number, you can look that up in the table of sales, and that will normally tell you which is the price — if the invoice/receipt details are sufficiently thorough, you can identify which lot at the price the sale belonged to. Clearly, if the receipt identifies a split lot, you have to choose which lot the returned item came from. Is that the earlier, the later, the cheaper, the more expensive lot? If you don't have a receipt, or the receipt details are inadequate, you probably end up guessing which lot it came from.

Comment: The recipt will show an aggregated cost and quantity. So item 1 qty = 150 items at $145 so if the customer want to return 10 from the 150 how would I know the cost of the 10 that I want to return and what bucket to return to?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a generic enough but oversimplified example of how your schema might look like

```sql
CREATE TABLE products
(
  `id` int not null auto_increment primary key, 
  `name` varchar(13), 
  `price` decimal(12, 2), -- current sale price. You might want to extract it into it's own table `prices`
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE orders
(
  `id` int not null auto_increment primary key, 
  `date` date,
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE order_items
(
  `id` int not null auto_increment primary key, 
  `order_id` int not null, 
  `product_id` int, 
  `quantity` decimal(12, 3), 
  `cost` decimal(12, 2),
  foreign key (`order_id`) references orders (id),
  foreign key (`product_id`) references products (id)
);

CREATE TABLE sales
(
  `id` int not null auto_increment primary key, 
  `date` datetime,
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE sale_items
(
  `id` int not null auto_increment primary key, 
  `sale_id` int not null, 
  `product_id` int, 
  `quantity` decimal(12, 3), 
  `price` decimal(12, 2),
  foreign key (`sale_id`) references sales (id),
  foreign key (`product_id`) references products (id)
);
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ed59)** demo

This gives you the ability to independently track your costs and sales.

---

One way to calculate total sales, total actual cost and margin per product

```sql
SELECT product_id, p.name, sales_quantity, sales_total, cost_total, sales_total - cost_total margin
  FROM
(
  SELECT product_id, sales_quantity, sales_total, SUM(
    CASE WHEN sales_quantity >= running_quantity 
           THEN cost * quantity
         WHEN sales_quantity BETWEEN running_quantity - quantity AND running_quantity
           THEN cost * (sales_quantity - (running_quantity - quantity))
          ELSE 0 
     END) cost_total
    FROM
  (
    SELECT s.*, o.cost, o.quantity, o.running_quantity
      FROM
    (
      SELECT product_id, 
             SUM(quantity * price) sales_total, 
             SUM(quantity) sales_quantity
      FROM sale_items
     GROUP BY product_id
    ) s JOIN 
    (
      SELECT product_id, cost, quantity, (
        SELECT SUM(quantity)
          FROM order_items
         WHERE product_id = i.product_id
           AND order_id <= i.order_id
         ) running_quantity
        FROM order_items i
    ) o
        ON s.product_id = o.product_id
  ) q
   GROUP BY product_id, sales_quantity, sales_total
) q JOIN products p
    ON q.product_id = p.id
```

Sample output:

```
| PRODUCT_ID |          NAME | SALES_QUANTITY | SALES_TOTAL | COST_TOTAL | MARGIN |
|------------|---------------|----------------|-------------|------------|--------|
|          1 | Coca-Cola 2.L |            150 |       187.5 |        145 |   42.5 |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8123a8/9)** demo

You may see that in the example first 100 bottles out of 150 sold cost $100 ($1*100), and the rest 50 cost $45 (0.9*50)

Comment: I am still not clear how this design will help me to identify the cost of each order. so I i sold an 2 items of product_id = 1 one cost me $1 and another cost me $0.9 how can this setup help me identify that my cost is $1.90? I do see that you are capturing the purchase/order separately but how can I determine the cost from that? How would I write a query to figure our the true cost?

Comment: IF you add a cost field into `sale_items` you can allocate two or more costs to an item. See [**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ed6bf/6)

Comment: the price value should be easy to get as it is stored in the product table. But, how would you figure out the `cost` value prior inserting a new record into the `sale_item` table?

Comment: @Mike Did it help in any way?

Comment: @peterm yes it did. I am still working on this trying to figure out the best approach to this problem. I am thank full for your answer and help but I am trying to stay away from having to write such a complex query unless I have too. I am trying to follow Jonathan Leffler suggestion above which will allow me to keep track of the cost at the transaction level and will also allow me to find out how many items left with their cost using FIFO system

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @FromDate DateTime=GetDate()
declare @ToDate DateTime=GetDate()
Select ToDateProfit.ProductID,ToDateProfit.Name,ToDateProfit.sales_quantity-   ISNULL(FromDateProfit.sales_quantity,0) as Sales_Quantity
,ToDateProfit.sales_total-ISNULL(FromDateProfit.sales_total,0) as Sales_Total
,ToDateProfit.cost_total-ISNULL(FromDateProfit.cost_total,0) as Cost_Total
,ToDateProfit.margin-ISNULL(FromDateProfit.margin,0) as Margin
 From
(
SELECT P.ProductID, p.name, sales_quantity, sales_total, cost_total, sales_total - cost_total margin
  FROM
(
  SELECT productid, sales_quantity, sales_total, SUM(
CASE WHEN sales_quantity >= running_quantity 
       THEN  PurchasePrice* quantity
     WHEN sales_quantity BETWEEN running_quantity - quantity AND running_quantity
       THEN PurchasePrice * (sales_quantity - (running_quantity - quantity))
      ELSE 0 
 END) cost_total
FROM
  (
SELECT s.*, o.PurchasePrice, o.quantity, o.running_quantity
  FROM
(
  SELECT ProductID, 
         SUM((quantity * UnitPrice)/ExchangeRate) sales_total, 
         SUM(quantity) sales_quantity
  FROM SaleDetail
  Inner Join Sale on Sale.SaleID=SaleDetail.SaleID
 where Convert(Date,Sale.SaleDate)<=Convert(date,@ToDate) --(must minus saledate <FromDate            (GetDate() is ToDate)         )
 GROUP BY ProductID
) s JOIN 
    (
  SELECT  productid, BuyingPrice/ExchangeRate as PurchasePrice, quantity, (
    SELECT SUM(quantity)
      FROM PurchaseDetail
     inner join Purchase Pur on Pur.PurchaseID=PurchaseDetail.PurchaseID 
     WHERE productid = i.productid
       AND Pur.Date <= PurI.date ----Fifo (if want lifo change <= to >=)
     ) running_quantity
    FROM PurchaseDetail i
    Inner join Purchase PurI on PurI.PurchaseID=i.PurchaseID
) o
ON s.productid = o.productid
)q
GROUP BY productid, sales_quantity, sales_total
) q JOIN product p
ON q.ProductID = p.ProductID
)ToDateProfit 
Left Join
(
SELECT P.ProductID, p.name, sales_quantity, sales_total, cost_total, sales_total - cost_total margin
FROM
(
SELECT productid, sales_quantity, sales_total, SUM(
CASE WHEN sales_quantity >= running_quantity 
       THEN  PurchasePrice* quantity
     WHEN sales_quantity BETWEEN running_quantity - quantity AND running_quantity
       THEN PurchasePrice * (sales_quantity - (running_quantity - quantity))
      ELSE 0 
 END) cost_total
FROM
(
SELECT s.*, o.PurchasePrice, o.quantity, o.running_quantity
FROM
(
SELECT ProductID, 
         SUM((quantity * UnitPrice)/ExchangeRate) sales_total, 
         SUM(quantity) sales_quantity
  FROM SaleDetail
  Inner Join Sale on Sale.SaleID=SaleDetail.SaleID
 where Convert(Date,Sale.SaleDate)<Convert(date,@FromDate) --(must minus saledate <FromDate            (GetDate() is ToDate)         )
 GROUP BY ProductID
) s JOIN 
(
  SELECT  productid, BuyingPrice/ExchangeRate as PurchasePrice, quantity, (
    SELECT SUM(quantity)
      FROM PurchaseDetail
     inner join Purchase Pur on Pur.PurchaseID=PurchaseDetail.PurchaseID 
     WHERE productid = i.productid
       AND Pur.Date <= PurI.date ----Fifo (if want lifo change <= to >=)
     ) running_quantity
    FROM PurchaseDetail i
    Inner join Purchase PurI on PurI.PurchaseID=i.PurchaseID 
) o    ON s.productid = o.productid 
) q 
GROUP BY productid, sales_quantity, sales_total
) q JOIN product p
ON q.ProductID = p.ProductID
)FromDateProfit on FromDateProfit.ProductID=ToDateProfit.ProductID
Inner Join ---------Only Product
(
Select Product.ProductID From Product
Inner Join SaleDetail On SaleDetail.ProductID=Product.ProductID
Inner Join Sale On Sale.SaleID=SaleDetail.SaleID
Where CONVERT(Date,SaleDate)>=CONVERT(Date,@FromDate) And  CONVERT(Date,SaleDate)<=CONVERT(Date,@ToDate)
Group By Product.ProductID)SP On SP.ProductID=ToDateProfit.ProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

"I want to ensure that I track my profit very accurately. Therefore, the 100 that I bought at $1 I want to be able to track those separately at the $1 cost and the new order at the $0.90 cost." - This is not necessary. You have to calculate current average price and calculate the profit using it. You have no serial numbers for each bottle and for that reason even if you want to know the profit for each item - you cannot do it. And from owner's viewpoint, it is important to know the total profit from Coca Cola, not that "from this bottle it is 0.50, and from that bottle it is 0.45".